# Calling constexpr function in enable_if_t

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, clang

Consider the following example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct A;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool f() { return true; }

template <typename T>
struct A<T, std::enable_if_t<f<T>()>> {};

int main() {
  A<int> f;
}
```

It compiles fine with [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/QH1tRq) and [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/HhboUw) but [MSVC gives the following error](https://godbolt.org/g/rQafsJ):

```
13 : <source>(13): error C2079: 'f' uses undefined struct 'A<int,void>'
```

Is it a bug in MSVC or the code and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can provide a definition for the `A`'s primary template, but I doubt that is the solution you are looking for...

Comment: Confirmed, on MinGW it works too

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost completely certain this is a MSVC bug.

Some testing reveals MSVC simply refuses to match to the specialized template, providing a definition and a `static_assert` in the primary template can be used to verify this.

After some digging [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/) popped up, and apparently using types in sfinae constructs works, but somehow not for functions.

The end result is [this workaround](https://godbolt.org/g/BmVJeP), which is slightly annoying but mostly bearable

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct A;

template <typename T>
struct f
{
    constexpr operator bool() {return true;}
};

template <typename T>
struct A<T, std::enable_if_t<(f<T>())>> {};  // note braces

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
}
```